# What type of graph should you use to describe a bus route?

Tags: graph-theory

If you have an acyclic bus route (The route goes from Point A to Point B only, doesn't go back) what type of graph should you use to accurately describe it?

I was thinking about using a [Simple Directed Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleDirectedGraph.html), but as shown in the diagrams that WolframAlpha provides, each node can be directed to multiple other nodes. In a bus route, the bus can only go from one stop to a single next stop in the stop list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good question to ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because each node goes to only one other node, does not make it any less a graph. Just a degenerate case of a graph. You still have the node properties and the arc properties of each connection.

Comment: Are you saying that I should just call it a simple directed graph?

Comment: yes, simple directed graph is what you described. Just because it "can" be directed to multiple nodes doesn't mean it "has" to be directed to multiple nodes. Your graph will simply have out-degree and in-degree of each node at most 1, which means it will describe a **path** which is exactly what the bus goes through.